# Increase performance on iphone at pdf rendering

Tags: iphone, performance, memory, pdf, uiimage

I have a UITableView, and in every cell there's displayed a UIImage created from a pdf. But now the performance is very bad. Here's my code I use to generate the UIImage from the PDF.

Creating CGPDFDocumentRef and UIImageView (in cellForRowAtIndexPath method):

```
...    
CFURLRef pdfURL = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(CFBundleGetMainBundle(), (CFStringRef)formula.icon, NULL, NULL);
CGPDFDocumentRef documentRef = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)pdfURL);
CFRelease(pdfURL);
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[self imageFromPDFWithDocumentRef:documentRef]];
...
```

Generate UIImage:

```
- (UIImage *)imageFromPDFWithDocumentRef:(CGPDFDocumentRef)documentRef {
    CGPDFPageRef pageRef = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(documentRef, 1);
    CGRect pageRect = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(pageRef, kCGPDFCropBox);

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(pageRect.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, CGRectGetMinX(pageRect),CGRectGetMaxY(pageRect));
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1, -1);  
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -(pageRect.origin.x), -(pageRect.origin.y));
    CGContextDrawPDFPage(context, pageRef);

    UIImage *finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return finalImage;
}
```

What can I do to increas the speed and keep the memory low?

Comment: Hi , i am doing like yours. I don't know what is formula.icon in your code. please could you please provide more?. thz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generating image from PDF for each cell in runtime seems like a huge performance hit.

You should try to consider maybe performing the actual rendering in the background thread and store the rendered result `UIImages` and populate them into the `UITableView` in runtime. This will at-least free up the UI thread and add responsiveness to application.

For the cells that are not yet rendered you can display a 'loading' message or add a 'activity indicator' spinner.